# Cloud scheduler redirect POST request with 308 status code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I created a cloud schedule task that calls an endpoint on my API. When I try to test it, it then returns a 308 status code and then does a GET request.

I tested the end point with thunder client and it works as it should and I have other tasks that are working correctly with the api

Any assistance would be amazing!

Comment: did you check the headers?

Comment: 308 means redirect. This can happen when authorization is required. Your question does not show the details on the request or the 308 Location response.

Comment: Could you solve it? Got the same problem